# SSRS Chart with Date Axis

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I want to create a chart in SSRS. My data contains timestamps when a state changes from 1 to 0, or vice versa:

```
Date                   Value
3/31/2011 4:44:38 PM   1 
4/4/2011 2:35:43 PM    0
4/4/2011 3:05:09 PM    1
4/4/2011 5:57:10 PM    0
4/4/2011 7:08:29 PM    1
4/4/2011 7:22:03 PM    0
4/4/2011 9:00:32 PM    1
...
```

I'd like the X Axis for the chart to show the full date range (which it does) and then show the data as a stepped line showing when the state changes from one to another. The problem is, SSRS doesn't treat the x axis as a date range and plot the values relatively- it seems to just treat each data point as a simple date-unaware plot for the chart. At the moment I get this:
[image]

But what I want is something where the data points are plotted relative to their datestamp - this would give you an indication of how long the state was either 1 or 0 - kind of like this poor mockup (the black line is what I want instead of the blue line):
[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Damn. In the end it was just a checkbox! I needed to go to the properties of the X Axis (the date range) and check "Scalar Axis". Done.

Comment: I missed that, too!! Such a simple fix.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed too. With hundreds of options it's a bit like looking for a needle in a haystack.